# Reference an object using an attribute other than its ID in the URL

Tags: java, android, database, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to build a simple register/log-in system for an Android app, using Spring boot. I have a MySQL database in a virtual machine that contains a table with columns **id**, **username**, **password**. The Spring boot application contains the following classes; `Account` (the entity), `AccountRepository` (the repository), `AppConfig` (the configuration class) and `Application` (main class). My endpoint is `/accounts`. If I want to see what accounts are currently registered I simply go to `http://<ip address>:8080/accounts` for a JSON representation of the database.

I want to modify my Android program so that if a user tries to register an account, it first checks to see if the username is already registered. The problem is that I'm not able to reference a username in the web repository - I have to use the account ID (e.g. `http://<ip address>:8080/accounts/2`).

Is there a way to modify my Spring boot application to allow me to reference usernames directly rather than through their IDs? So rather than having my Android app looping over each database entry I can send a request to a URL such as `http://<ip address>:8080/accounts/johnstone01` to see what response I get (if the response is 200 for instance then I know that the username already exists and consequently make the user choose a different username).

Highly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest create POST request `http://<ip address>:8080/accounts` for creating account and make username checking inside. It might be MySQL-level checking using constraints.

As for separate checking of username existence I suggest to modify GET request by adding query parameter "username":

```
http://<ip address>:8080/accounts?username=johnstone01
```

in this case response will return array with only one record or will return empty array if such username does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're making a REST API for your server. In this case the right way to do is to create an endpoint that will accept a POST request (e.g. POST http://:8080/accounts the post request will contain user informations).

From your app if someone tries to register a new account you'll send a POST request to the endpoint you defined with the information to create the new account. All the rest will happend in your service layer. It seems that you don't have one, it's ok for a small project, I guess the service code is in your controller. This mean your controller have the responsibility to check if the entity can be persisted and if yes, will do so.

In your repository just add a method that will accept as a parameter the username and return the entry for that username or null. This way your controller can request it, if it's null then it can persist the new entity and return a HTTP code 200 if not it should return a 409 Conflict code.

Your app then only have to check the return code to know what happend.